# Why does the FTC not require patent numbers to be included in television commercials?

Tags: false-marking, false-marketing

This is only broadly related to patents but maybe someone on here knows. Why is it not required to show a patent number when a product claims to be "patented?"

Building off that, if a product claims to be patented, and it turns out that is a lie, is that punishable by law? I believe this is called False Marking, based on the definition I found [here](http://www.klemchuk.com/390-Patent-False-Marking-Generally).

Comment: I think this question is better suited on Law.SE